# Different way to do this without adding if's

Tags: java

I have four methods that set the field result to ok or ko, depending on some conditions. But I don't want to execute method2 if result was already set to ko in method1. Is there a way to do this without having to add an if before every method?

```
public void check {
   method1(dto, a);
   method2(dto, a, b);
   method3();
   method4();
}

private void method1(Object dto, int a) {
   if(a == 2)
      dto.setResult("ko");
   else
      dto.setResult("ok");
}

private void method2(Object dto, int a, int b) {
   if(a + b == 5)
      dto.setResult("ok");
   else
      dto.setResult("ko");
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Combine the methods. `if (a+b != 5 || a == 2) dto.setReult("ko"); else dto.setResult("ok");`

Comment: It's an example, I need to have them separated.